# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "posts"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image: Having an error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "posts"]

I'm trying to enter comments on POST but,i don't know  where i'm lacking.It showing me an error just after making me comment.

Comment: The mongoose id should be 24 characters HEX value.

Comment: It's having 24 characters sir

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think `_id` is of `string` type.  Could try casting it to `ObjectId()` using mongoose?